# Background covering webpage when the images width is much smaller than its height

Tags: html, css, image

What is the best approach to dealing with images whos height is much MUCH larger than their width in regards to covering the background?

The image I have is 1026x2258 (width x height) and displays HORRIBLY.

Are there any tricks to deal with this scenario? There isnt much more cropping that can be done with the image.

It should ideally fit in a div container with a height of around 1700-1800px, however with that width it has to manipulate so much that you hardly see the image.

Comment: You can try using a combination of css background-size and background-position, this way you can maybe set the background-size to cover, then move it up and down with position.

Comment: Did you try to use `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: Yes, it gets me close but doesnt display as well as I need it to

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center`

That way you can see the middle of the image

Comment: Note that Safari has some issues with background-cover the last time I checked (about 6 months ago). In order to get around this I used [jQuery.backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Comment: Yes, it gets me close but doesnt display as well as I need it to, going to play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use various image sizes, it may take more work to arrange, but will load faster and can be adapted by css.

Try something like:

```
@media(max-width:2250px){
  .image{background-image: url('../images/2258x1026.jpg')}
}
@media(max-width:1920px){
  .image{background-image: url('../images/1920x1080.jpg')}
}
/*@media(max-width:1920px){ <- width of screen
  .image{background-image: url('../images/1920x1080.jpg')} <- image for this screen
}*/
```

Comment: this is what I was going to end up doing, was hoping their was some nice cool trick.

Comment: I understand, I've done some tests, but nothing as significant as this example posted. The real problem is in charge of transfer client-server.

Comment: This doesnt help as much as I was hoping, the image I have has a width of 1000px while the height is 1900, the larger the screen width, the larger the height... For a 1920px width, were looking at a height of over 3000px to keep aspect ratio. This also means the height of the container needs to be over 3000px which is quite a bit of scrolling!